# Excel: Convert Column of Duplicates into a New List, AND THEN create into a DROPDOWN LIST

Tags: excel-formula

I have a CSV Product Export from Shopify. I am creating a manual offline quote sheet for furniture items.

[image: VIEW IMAGE: Convert DUPLICATES to LIST into DROPDOWN LIST]

- Column B = Product Title
- Column A = Product Title's Handle (obtained using an Index formula)

PROBLEM:

- Column D = Duplicates need to be converted into a list.
- THEN using above formula add to a new cell for a Drop Down list (Add formula into Data Validation:Source.)

Note based on the image diagram: Ref 'I2' is located far top left where it says 'Aurora Chair 4 Leg'

---

NOTES,
And this formula is enetered into 'I3',
=XLOOKUP(I2,A2:A16,D2:D16)

.. but, this formula only returns 'D2', not D2:D5

I also unsuccessfully tried,

- =indirect(I2,A2:A16,D2:D16)
- =XLOOKUP((I2,A2:A16,0)RANGE D2:D16))
- =index(I2,A2:D16)
- =FILTER(A2:D16,D2:D16=I3)
- {=SUM(COUNTIF(A2:A16,D2:D16))}
- =COUNTIF(A2:A16,VLOOKUP(I3,D2:D16,1,0))

Comment: Is my understanding correct, that you want a *unique* list - not a list of duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula for a unique list of filtered values:

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(D2:D16,A2:A16=I2))`

You can't use this formula as a data validation source :-(

Therefore you have to put it somewhere (hidden) on the sheet, e.g. into cell `K2`.

And then refer to it as `K2#` in the data validation source.

**Edit according to comment:**

To show the values in a row instead of column you use:
`=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(D2:D16,A2:A16=I2)))`

Comment: This is a success! Very pleased, THANK YOU. The formula uses Column A to return a unique list from Column D. I am now looking at transposing the Column D results to save space as a row of results instead of a column...and from there will try the validation.

Comment: You can use the `TRANSPOSE` formula